# Sum duplicate rows and then delete all duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Sheet where some rows may contain the same data as other rows, except for one column. I need a macro to sum all the values in that column and delete all the duplicates, except for the first one, which contains the sum of the rest. For example:

```
   A   B   C   D
1  a   b   c   d
2  n   j   i   o
3  a   b   c   p
4  v   y   e   b
5  a   b   c   m
6  .   .   .   .
```

In this case, the code must delete rows 3 and 5 (because they are "duplicates" of row 1), and replace the column D of row 1 with d+p+m. I managed to come up with the following code:

```
For j = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = j + 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(i, 1).value And Cells(j, 2).value = Cells(i, 2).value And Cells(j, 3).value = Cells(i, 3).value Then
            Cells(j, 6) = Cells(i, 6).value + Cells(j, 6).value
            Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

But as you may have already noticed, it's very inefficient and basic. Any better ideas?

Comment: Concatenate a,b and c then sort it and use built in excel subtotal to sum d at every change in concatenation? Edit: no delete though :/

Comment: lol @Jeeped I was in the middle of writing an answer XD

Comment: @findwindow If it's different from the ones pointed out by Jeeped, then go ahead... the more options, the better :)

Comment: Can't. Question is closed.

Comment: Two closely related answers already on the site would be [Combine Rows & Sum Values in a Worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384575/combine-rows-sum-values-in-a-worksheet) for summing and deleting duplicates and [Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o/32546352#32546352) demonstrates string concatenation as well as summing values.

Comment: @findwindow It has been undeleted, I would like to see your approach.

Comment: @findwindow - I've consolidated the links to a single comment and reopened the question if you want to take a crack at it.

Comment: lol not going to embarrass myself if Scott already posted an answer XD

Comment: @findwindow you put too much credit in my abilities,  Yours may be better.

Comment: lol I have seen your answers. I went non vba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code:

```
Sub remdup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrw As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastrw = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrw).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFs(C[-1],C[-4],RC[-4],C[-3],RC[-3],C[-2],RC[-2])"
    ws.Range("D1:D" & lastrw).Value = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrw).Value
    ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrw).ClearContents
    With ws.Range("A1:D" & lastrw)
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2, 3), xlNo
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yea. Better than mine ^_^;

Comment: What if there are more columns to sum? Let's say I also have values in columns E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, etc... which also need to be grouped when values in A, B and C coincide. Is this method still efficient?

Comment: @N.Pavon you would just need to add the logic to place the sumifs in an empty column then move the values, this is not using loops so it is still very efficient.

Comment: But what if there were 55 columns with values that need to be added, would it be better to use a loop to fill the "empty" columns and then move them?

Comment: It can be done without  loops,  that is the beauty of R1C1. @N.Pavon

Comment: Can you enlighten me? I actually don't understand the use of R1C1 :(

Comment: So if there were 55 columns: `Range("BM1:BM" & lastrw).Resize(,55).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFs(C[-61],C1,RC1,C2,RC2,C3,RC3)"` Then `Range("D1:D" & lastrw).resize(,55).Value = Range("BM1:BM" & lastrw).Resize(,55).Value`then `Range("BM1:BM" & lastrw).Resize(,55).ClearContents` @N.Pavon

Comment: @N.Pavon I changed something in the last comment make sure you use the edit.